# Need 3 outcomes from IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a list of names in excel which have a random number next to them in brackets, the numbers are 1 to 3 digits long.

I was using the formula

```
=IF(LEFT(RIGHT(B8,4),1)=("("),RIGHT(B8,3),RIGHT(B8,4))
```

to get rid of the first bracket and then

```
=IF(RIGHT(LEFT(AX8,3),1)=")",LEFT(AX8,2),LEFT(AX8,3))
```

to remove the last bracket.

This was working until I found a name with a 4 digit number in the brackets.
Is there a way to add another outcome to the if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VALUE-function-257D0108-07DC-437D-AE1C-BC2D3953D8C2) will interpret bracketed numbers as negative but the [ABS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ABS-function-3420200F-5628-4E8C-99DA-C99D7C87713C) will take care of that.

```
=ABS(VALUE(MID(A2, FIND("(", A2), 99)))
```

An additional bonus is that you end up with true numbers, not text that looks like a number.

Comment: Good point! The text-to-number conversion built into the ABS function's overhead should be sufficient. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: as long as there is nothing after the brackets and there is never a negative number, it will be a fast solution... *+1*

Answer (score 2):

why not use:

```
=MID(LEFT(B8,FIND(")",B8)-1),FIND("(",B8)+1,99)
```

to do it in one step? (no need for IF or knowing the length of your number)

Answer (score 0):

You can have three or more results when you use nested IF conditions, e.g.: 
    =IF(a1=b1; "equal";IF(a1>b1;"greater";"smaller"))